# Redirecting using window.location.replace not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for whatever reason my code won't redirect to another file after I press submit.

```
      $('form').submit(function () {
      window.location.replace('test.html');  });
```

I have defined everything in an html file. Any ideas?

Thanks,
busterroni

Answer (score 5):

You need to stop the form from submitting. That can be done by calling `preventDefault()` on the event object that is passed in.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace('test.html');  
});
```

Not cancelling the form submission, you created a race condition. You had the form submitting back to the current page and you had the location trying to navigate away.

If you want the back button to work, you probably want to use `assign()` and not `replace()`.

Comment: Yup - this makes more sense